# Folio con id autoincrementable y año actual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Necesito crear un numero de `folio` en base a `id` que se registro en ese momento,`EST` y el año actual, solo seria el `19`.

Tengo esta parte donde se hace el `insert` el cual funciona perfectamente.

```
            $query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_list (folio,description_item,price_item,manufacturer,model_item,
            reorder_Level,target_Stock,image,registerDate,commentt,fkEngineer,fkCategory,fkLocation,fkSupplier,fkUnit,fkSubCat)
            VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';


            $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array('EST'.'-'.$year,$_POST['description_item'], $_POST['price_item'] ,
            $_POST['manufacturer'], $_POST['model_item'], $_POST['reorder_Level'], $_POST['target_Stock'], $_POST['imageName'],
            $hoy, $_POST['commentt'] ,$_POST['fkEngineer'],$_POST['fkCategory'],$_POST['fkLocation'],$_POST['fkSupplier'],$_POST['fkUnit'],$_POST['fkSubCat']));
if ($result > 0)
                {....}
```

El folio creado necesito que se guarde en la columna `folio` de la tabla `inventory_list` como se muestra.

Este id es autoincrementable,actualmente solo hice que se registrara asi `EST-19`,eso lo hago asi `'EST'.'-'.$year` pero me falta el `id` que se registro en ese momento.

Ejemplo:

Tengo registrado `10` datos, el siguiente registro es el `11`, tomamos su `id` y lo concatenamos.

El problema que tengo es que no se como obtener el `id` y juntarlo con la otra parte que ya tengo.

Deberia de quedar asi: `EST-id-19`

Answer (score 1):

Con un procedimiento almacenado logras realizar lo que solicitas,
- primero insertas en tu tabla
- después obtienes el ultimo id ingresado
- y por ultimo actualizas tu tabla

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Agregar_inventory_list`(
in xfolio text,
in xdescription_item text,
in xanio int
)
BEGIN
declare v_id int(11);
insert into inventory_list(folio,description_item) values(xfolio,xdescription_item);
select max(id) into v_id  from inventory_list;
update inventory_list set concatenado=concat('EST','-',v_id,'-',xanio) where id=v_id;
END
```

Comment: Muy buena opción.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que al hacer un count simple de la BD, si hay muchos registros vas a tener errores (me ha pasado) como repetir el id, entonces lo que puedes hacer es crear un id autoincrementable en mysql y al hacer el insert de tus datos obtener el ID insertado con

```
//conectamos
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');
//creamos query
$query = "  INSERT INTO users
            (firstname, lastname)
            VALUES (:firstname, :lastname)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);

//ejecutamos
$stmt->execute();

//obtenemos id insertado
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Es autoincrementable y es clave primaria...Existe manera de obtener el `id` que se esta registrando en ese momento para concatenar, mire en algunas paginas la sentencia `insert_last_id`, pero no supe como usarlo.

Comment: Los id de mysql generalmente deben ser enteros, pero si ya lo estás manejando como string debes obtener el id, pensé que estbas usando mysqli, ¿es PDO? si es así, perdona, ya edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Si es PDO, pensaba que tal vez después de que se hiciera el insert obtener el ultimo id, o el max y luego hacer un update a la columna, pero si hay una forma mas fácil, agradecería que me orientes.

Comment: Ahi te puse el código para obtener el $id, con eso ya lo puedes obtener y trabajar en una nueva query para actualizar tu folio, repito, no creo que sea lo más correcto usar el folio como id, ahora, si no obtienes nada, con el lastInsertId podría ser por que busca un campo id, te recomiendo que sean dos campos serparados id, folio, decription, etc...